# MySQL loop through tables

Tags: mysql

I want to output data from every table that contains a `first_name` column. I put together the following procedure, but in my loop, mysql interprets the table name literally instead of evaluating the variable `table_name`. What's the fix?

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists hunt //
create procedure hunt()
begin
    DECLARE done int default false;
    DECLARE table_name CHAR(255);

    DECLARE cur1 cursor for SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "wholesale_production" and COLUMN_NAME LIKE "%first%" ;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cur1;

    myloop: loop
        fetch cur1 into table_name;
        if done then
            leave myloop;
        end if;
        select * from `wholesale_production`.table_name where created_at >= '2012-10-01';
    end loop;

    close cur1;
end //

delimiter ;

call hunt();
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
delimiter //

drop procedure if exists hunt //
create procedure hunt()
begin
    DECLARE done BOOL default false;
    DECLARE tablename CHAR(255);

    DECLARE cur1 cursor for SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "wholesale_production" and COLUMN_NAME LIKE "%first%" ;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cur1;

    myloop: loop
        fetch cur1 into tablename;
        if done then
            leave myloop;
        end if;
        set @sql = CONCAT('select * from `wholesale_production`.', tablename, ' where created_at >= ''2012-10-01''');
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        drop prepare stmt;
    end loop;

    close cur1;
end //

delimiter ;

call hunt();
```

Comment: I have a similar problem. If I don't care about filtering the table name to be `LIKE '%first%'`, can I just use `SHOW TABLES` instead of `SELECT TABLE_NAME ...`?

Comment: table_name is a reserved name. should be changed to a different name.

Comment: SELECT distinct TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "wholesale_production" ;

Answer (score 1):

a little edit of the above to itertate ahtoug all the tables and select them.

```
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists hunt //
create procedure hunt()
begin
    DECLARE done int default false;
    DECLARE table_name CHAR(255);

    DECLARE cur1 cursor for SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
                  WHERE table_schema ='mbu4u';
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    open cur1;
       myloop: loop
        fetch cur1 into table_name;
        if done then
            leave myloop;
        end if;
        set @sql = CONCAT('select * from `mbu4u`.',table_name);
        prepare stmt from @sql;
        execute stmt;
        drop prepare stmt;
    end loop;

    close cur1;
end //

delimiter //
```

Answer (score 1):

table_name is a reserved token use another variable name in "DECLARE table_name CHAR(255);"

Answer (score -3):

in cur1 you are using TABLE_NAME there try using a real name of the table

Comment: But the table isn't known, he's getting table names from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.