# Convert from utf8_general_ci to utf8_unicode_ci

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I have a utf8_general_ci database that I'm interested in converting to utf8_unicode_ci.
I've tried the following commands

```
    ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
    ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; (for every single table)
```

But that seems to change the charset for future data but doesn't convert the actual existing data from utf8_general_ci to utf8_unicode_ci.
Is there any way to convert the existing data to utf8_unicode_ci?

Comment: I think this should help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445969/how-to-change-collation-of-all-rows-from-latin1-swedish-ci-to-utf8-unicode-ci

Answer (score 2):

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` to see if it really set the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` on the *columns*, not just the defaults.

What was the `CHARACTER SET` *before* the `ALTERs`?

Do `SELECT col, HEX(col) ...` for some field that *should* have utf8 in it.  This will help us determine if you really have utf8 in the table.  The *encoding* for characters is different based on `CHARACTER SET`; the `HEX` helps discover such.

The *ordering* (`WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, etc) is controlled by `COLLATION`.  The indexes probably had to be rebuilt based on your `ALTER TABLE`.  Did big tables with indexes take a 'long' time to convert?

To actually see the difference between `utf8_general_ci` and `utf8_unicode_ci`, you need a "combining accent" or, more simply, the German `ß` versus `ss`:

```
mysql> SELECT 'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
              'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
| 'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE utf8_general_ci  | 'ß' = 'ss' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci  |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
|                                   0 |                                   1 |
+-------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

However, to test that in your tables, you would need to store those values and use `WHERE` or `GROUP_CONCAT` or something else to determine the equality.

What 'proof' do you have that the `ALTERs` failed to achieve the collation change?

(Addressing other comments:  `REPAIR` should be irrelevant.  `CONVERT TO` tells the `ALTER` to actually modify the data, so it should have done the desired action.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the collation of every field in every table. As you say, the collation of the table is only the default value for fields created later, and the collation of the database is only the default value for tables created later.

Comment: How may I change the collation of every field in every table?

Comment: What if you `REPAIR` the whole table? It would rebuild it with the new collation.

Answer (score 0):

As Lorenz Meyer said, the collation of the table is only the default value for fields created later and you need to set the defaults for the columns explicitly too.

Such a change looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE mycolumn mycolumn varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```